# Utilizar dados existentes no banco para autenticação

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, estrutura-de-dados, autenticação, estilo-de-codificação

Tenho um banco de dados com dados já existentes, com nome, CPF, RG e outros dados pessoais. Preciso implementar um sistema de login, mas queria que o usuário fosse no caso o numero de registro e a senha o CPF, por exemplo. Nas demonstrações de como fazer o login, sempre me indicam a fazer um novo model com usuário e senha. Ai pergunto, poderia usar a mesma tabela da qual já tenho os dados pessoais para fazer o login, ou teria que copiar os dados dessa tabela para um model novo, dedicado somente ao User?

E se eu quisesse deixar o usuário logar tanto com e-mail, quanto com numero de registro? Como faria essa consulta?

Comment: Dá pra fazer, mas a estrutura vai ficar estranha. Sugiro você criar uma rotina de migração de dados, onde ele alimente a nova tabela de login com os dados já existente. Se você optar por manter os dados assim, como vai fazer para o usuário alterar a senha ? O e-mail do Usuário já está presente na tabela existente?

Comment: Olá, Victor. Ainda não, os emails só estariam disponíveis depois que os usuarios atualizarem seus cadastros. O que eu ainda não consigo entender é como usar os dados da tabela presenta para autenticar. Basta copiar os dafos das colunas que eu quero usar para autenticar para a tabela criada pelo novo model?

Comment: Duvida: Na sua aplicação cada pessoa cadastrada vai ser um usuário ?

Comment: Sim, cada pessoa cadastrada é um usuário. Eles podem logar no sistema para alterar seus dados cadastrais.

Comment: Ok, nesse caso, é mais fácil você criar um campo senha, nessa mesma tabela, e joga o CPF do cara pra esse campo (como padrão), cabe a você criptografar essa senha ou não. Aproveita e cria junto o campo e-mail. Oque acha? Partindo dessa definição, qual o próximo problema ?

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu estava pensando em fazer. Até porque, se eu copiasse os dados para um outro model, a cada associado cadastrado, eu teria que migrar os dados. Enfim, só me resta dúvidas a como permitir que o username seja tanto o registro quanto o email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse caso, é mais fácil você criar um campo senha, nessa mesma tabela, e joga o CPF do cara pra esse campo (como padrão), cabe a você criptografar essa senha ou não. Aproveita e cria junto o campo e-mail

Primeiro faz uma validação no que o cara digitou, com regex, com isso você direciona para validação do e-mail ou nome. Para a validação em Ruby, segue o link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993545/ruby-email-validation-with-regex

A partir dai a validação é normal. com base noque você tem para aquele registro.